# Defined variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am hitting up mongo (via mongoose `customer.find()`) and getting back something that looks like

```
[{ _id: 5029a09e099fb5095fdb2d73,
  clientId: 22,
  company: 'X',
  email: 'X@Y.ca',
  firstName: 'X',
  lastName: 'Y',
  quality: 'Sold',
  address: 
   { phone: '',
     alt: '',
     street1: '',
     street2: '',
     city: '',
     state: 'Ontario',
     country: 'Canada',
     code: '' },
  comments: []
}]
```

Please note that this is the result from console.log directly. This is not something I am entering, this is the results from mongoDB. _id is being returned in this form by mongo and  has absolutely nothing to do with the issue.

when I try

`console.log(customer[0])` I get

```
{ _id: 5029a09e099fb5095fdb2d73,
      clientId: 22,
      company: 'X',
      email: 'X@Y.ca',
      firstName: 'X',
      lastName: 'Y',
      quality: 'Sold',
      address: 
       { phone: '',
         alt: '',
         street1: '',
         street2: '',
         city: '',
         state: 'Ontario',
         country: 'Canada',
         code: '' },
      comments: []
    }
```

as expected

when I try `console.log(customer[0].quality)` I get `undefined`

when I try `console.log(customer[0].email)` or any of the others it works fine, and I get the expected value.

to my knowledge, quality isn't a reserved word, am I missing something?

Comment: Uhh, shouldn't `_id` be a string? You don't have quotes around it.

Comment: @Amaan is right, the result of above is SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal

Comment: that is a copy paste from console.log

Comment: @Amaan is right nevertheless.

Comment: what do you get if you call `console.log(customer[0]['quality'])` ?

Comment: What do you get from `Object.keys(customer[0])`?

Comment: [ '_events',
  '_maxListeners',
  '_strictMode',
  '_doc',
  '_activePaths',
  '_saveError',
  '_validationError',
  'isNew',
  '_pres',
  '_posts',
  'save',
  'errors' ]

Comment: Have you tried `for(var prop in customer[0]) { console.log(prop); }` ?  Do you see `quality` in the output list?

Comment: no it's not there. That is interesting, I wonder why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose [find](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-find) returns Query object. It  not just plain javascript object. It inherits methods of your model, query methods, methods of Document. console.log shows you just toString method result of this object. It may be modified by getters or virtuals. _id without quotes also toString result of ObjectId class. Try access your value by customer[0].get('quality'); Or convert it to plain object via customer[0].toObject();

Answer (score 0):

I took you data inserted into mongo, ran the query console.log email, quality etc.

Everything worked as expected, no undefined insight.

I'm not using Mongoose, [mongojs](https://github.com/gett/mongojs) instead so perhaps there is bug in mongoose.

Answer (score -1):

this is working fine :

```
var customer = [{ _id: "5029a09e099fb5095fdb2d73",  clientId: 22,  company: 'X',  email: 'X@Y.ca',  firstName: 'X',  lastName: 'Y',  quality: 'Sold',  address:    { phone: '',     alt: '',     street1: '',     street2: '',     city: '',     state: 'Ontario',     country: 'Canada',     code: '' },  comments: []}]
console.log(customer[0].quality) // it will give Sold

make _id:5029a09e099fb5095fdb2d73 to _id:"5029a09e099fb5095fdb2d73"
```